# Is there any way to split a single string in a pandas column into multiple columns when I don't have any delimiter in there?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a column in  a pandas dataframe like this :

```
    C
0  1100
1  1011
2  2013
3  3210
```

I want to have four different columns from this column like this:

```
   E F G H 
0  1 1 0 0
1  1 0 1 1
2  2 0 1 3
3  3 2 1 0
```

I have used a custom function split_string to get the same by applying across the dataframe .

```
def split_string(s):
    return list(map(lambda i:i,s))
```

By applying this function across the column of the dataframe I can get it as follows for a single column:

```
       new 
0  [1 ,1 ,0 ,0]
1  [1 ,0 ,1 ,1]
2  [2 ,0 ,1 ,3]
3  [3 ,2 ,1 ,0]
```

But for multiple columns it is not working . If there is any workaround to this kindly suggest .

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame([[int(i) for i in str(num)] for num in df.C])``?

Comment: pd.DataFrame([[i for i in str(num)] for num in df.C]) this one can work but I need to do it in the same dataframe because if I will be creating a new dataframe how can I merge it to the original dataframe without any column serving as the base for joining?

Comment: @nikhil_ghanghor - Also dont need append to original DataFrame? Because accepting answer not.

Comment: @jezrael both of them helped me figure out the problem so I accepted both of them in a way or other . Thanks to you too .

Comment: @nikhil_ghanghor - So dont need add to original? Also dont need numbers? Need strings?

Comment: @nikhil_ghanghor - If yes, OK, accepting solution do it. My is different, convert values to numbers and add columns to original.

Comment: @jezrael I needed strings but your answer helped me how can we add a dataframe to another without having any common columns so in that sense both the answers worked out in my favour.

Comment: @nikhil_ghanghor - So output columns have to be strings? I think `1` is not number `1` but string `'1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with convert values to numbers for DataFrame and then add to original columns by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
L = [list(map(int, str(x))) for x in df['C']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index, columns=['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])

df = df.join(df1)
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
      C  E  F  G  H
0  1100  1  1  0  0
1  1011  1  0  1  1
2  2013  2  0  1  3
3  3210  3  2  1  0
```

Comment: Is it better and faster than using apply?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
In [1794]: res = pd.DataFrame(df.C.apply(lambda x: list(str(x))).tolist(), columns=['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])

In [1795]: res
Out[1795]: 
   E  F  G  H
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  1
2  2  0  1  3
3  3  2  1  0
```